# Tranferring an iMovie project from iPhone to MacBook Pro

Tags: imovie

Is it possible to transfer an iMovie *project* from my iPhone to my MacBook Pro?

Right now, my project consists of clips that I shot directly using iMovie, but they don't appear in my Camera Roll on my iPhone. Is there a way to make them appear on my Camera Roll (or other folder) so that I can simply copy and paste the *individual* clips onto my computer?

I have tried the new update of iMovie 10.1, but it gives a strange error when I try to import. What I have done:

1. Goto the projects in iMovie for iPhone, open a project, export to iTunes.
2. Download the "projectname.iMovieMobile" file from iTunes onto my computer.
3. Open iMovie version **10.1** (the new update). File > Import iMovie iOS Projects... > select the project.iMovieMobile.
4. When I try to import them, it gives an error after a few seconds:

   > Error in iOS Project Import
   >   Failed to import iOS project. The project's version is too old. Please update the iMovie app on your iOS device.

However, I have checked that I have the correct versions. I will try updating my iOS and get back to here.

---

*Additional Info*:

- Mac Book Pro (Late 2011)

  - I just installed the 'El Capitan' update, but it doesn't to appear to actually be working; will try reinstalling.
- iPhone 6S, iOS version 9.0.2 (latest)
- iMovie (on MacBook Pro) v. 10.1
- iMovie (on iPhone) v. 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I finally found my own solution:

1. **Make sure you have the latest versions of iMovie, *especially on iOS***. This was the main problem causer for me, as iMovie claimed to be updated and would not show up in the updates in the App Store until I restarted several times.
2. From your iPhone: export the project you wish to transfer to iTunes. Connect your iPhone to your computer via a USB cable and download the `filename.iMovieMobile` file to your computer.
3. Open iMovie on your computer, and click `File > Import iMovie iOS Projects...`.
4. You should have the project imported to iMovie on the computer! Now, you can even transfer to Final Cut Pro X (see [here](http://help.apple.com/imovie/mac/10.1/#/movcbf7e2a3f) for info on how to do that).

   > Make sure you are running the most recent versions of iMovie!